# Classification actions of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, group-actions

This is a very elementary question, but I'm having trouble finding anything explicit about it: Consider a finite group $G$ with an action on a finite set $X$. Is there a classification of such actions up to isomorphism (bijections on the set $X$)?

If I had to guess, I would say that we can first decompose $X$ into invariant subsets. The action on each subset is just the action of $G$ onto the cosets of some subgroup $H$. Since I couldn't find anything along this lines, I assume this is wrong; in this case, what would be examples of actions which don't arise in that way?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less correct. Every action is a disjoint union of transitive actions and transitive actions are classified up to isomorphism by conjugacy classes of subgroups. There is no need to require that either $G$ or $X$ is finite.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! So the transitive actions for two different subgroups related by conjugation are isomorphic by bijections on $X$, even if we keep $G$ fixed?

Comment: Of course whether that constitutes a "classification" is subjective, since classifying the conjugacy classes of subgroups of a group is in general extremely difficult (for instance we don't know how to do it for the symmetric group).

Comment: @CaptainLama Sure, I guess what I meant is a characterization by something simpler or at least better known. Such as subgroups.

Comment: @Andi: yes, this is a nice exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would say that we can first decompose $X$ into invariant subsets.

By "invariant" subset do you mean that $G\cdot A\subseteq A$? If so, then you're on the right track. We have to push that idea to the limit, i.e. by taking minimal invariant subsets, or in other words: orbits. Lets add some formalism first.

Given a group $G$ a pair $(X,\cdot)$ is called a $G$-set, if $X$ is a set and $\cdot:G\times X\to X$ is a group action on $X$. With this approach we say that a function $f:X\to Y$ between two $G$-sets is $G$-equivariant if $f(g\cdot x)=g\cdot f(x)$ for any $g\in G$ and $x\in X$. With that two $G$-sets $X$ and $Y$ are $G$-isomorphic if there are $G$-equivariant maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g=id$ and $g\circ f=id$. This can be shown to be equivalent to the fact that there is a $G$-equivariant bijection $X\to Y$.

All of this is done so that we can precisely define what "the same" or "isomorphic" for $G$-sets mean. To catch the true nature of action, regardless of labeling of elements. And with that we have the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a $G$-set. Then $X$ is $G$-isomorphic to the disjoint union $\bigsqcup X_i$, where each $X_i$ is $G$-isomorphic to $G/H$ for some subgroup $H\subseteq G$. The decomposition is unique up to $G$-isomorphism. Moreover $G/H$ is $G$-isomorphic to $G/H'$ if and only if $H$ is conjugate to $H'$.

Note that neither $G$ nor $X$ are assumed to be finite. This holds for arbitrary group and $G$-set.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any reference where this statement is proven? Or would this be considered too elementary to give a reference (say, I wanted to use this in a physics paper)?

Comment: @AndiBauer this is more or less classical result from the group theory, likely considered basic. If you need a reference then you can use "Transformation Groups and Representation Theory" by Tammo tom Dieck. Although he doesn't really prove that, he just states these facts in chapter 1.1. For proofs you can have a look at  "Group actions and applications" by K. N. Raghavan paper. Unfortunately it isn't officially published (available online though), it does not have references, it doesn't quote anything. It isn't really a book. I couldn't find better resources.